# Rich Text Box Not Printing Whole Record

Tags: c#, sql-server, richtextbox

i am doing this

```
while (myReader.Read())          
  {
    richTextBox1.Text =(myReader["District Name"].ToString());
  }
```

but this only prints last saved value of District Name to Rich Text Box but i want to print all the values in the column District Name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are setting the Text property each time rather than appending to it.

Use the following code instead:

```
richTextBox1.Text += (myReader["District Name"].ToString());
```

Answer (score 2):

use `+=` instead of equal to concatenate.

With equal, you assign a new value at each loop step.

You may use a `StringBuilder` for performances by the way (string concatenation can become quickly expensive), and assign the `StringBuilder's` value to your `TextBox` at the end of the loop.

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
while (myReader.Read())
   sb.AppendFormat(" {0}",myReader["District Name"].ToString());  //add a space between values if you need it.      
   //or sb.AppendLine(myReader["District Name"].ToString()); if you want them on different lines

myTextBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
```